# Does $o(x)$ show the order of Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If we have :
$$
\sin x= x-\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{x^{5}}{5 !} +o\left(x^{5}\right)
$$

and $$
\sin x=
x-\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{x^{5}}{5 !}
+o\left(x^{6}\right).
$$

Is the order of the first expression of $\sin(x)$ 5, and the order of the second one $6$?

If so, why then can we replace $o(x^6)$ with $o(x^5)$?
I know it's because as $x$ tends to $0$, $o(x^6)$ is a subset of $o(x^5)$ but won't the order change if we replace $o(x^6)$ with $o(x^5)$?

Comment: Do you mean to use big O notation?

Comment: You can replace $o(x^5)$ with $o(x^6)$ because, as  $\sin$ is an odd function, the expansion at order $5$ is also the expansion at order $6$.

Comment: @sunspots: I don't think so: the O.P. is  playing with *Taylor-Young's expansion*.

Comment: @Bernard who is Young?

Comment: I just want to know if the power of x in the little o notation determine the order of taylor expansion.

Comment: @sunspots: : William-Henry Young was an English mathematician who lived in the second half of the 19th and the first half of the 20th centuries, and formulated this version of Taylor's formula in terms of asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @ElieMakdissi: Yes – when you write $+o(x^5)$, it means you consider an expansion at order $5$, and with $o(x^6)$, an expansion at order $6$. This is required by the fact that in an expression, all terms have to be expanded at the same order.

Comment: @sunspots : no it's little o-notation not big O

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of the expression"? Formal definition please.

Comment: @Bernard : thanks a lot, it's clear now.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : It means in Taylor expansion there is order n, where like the “First-order” means including only the first two terms of the Taylor series, and first order means up to 1st derivative, i mean at the first derivative we should stop the expansion. I don't know if you understood my point because I didn't find a formal definition on google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little-o means the following:

> If $f\in o(g(x))$, as $x\to a$ (here the value $a$ is $0$; with Taylor series in general $a$ will be the centrepoint of the expansion), then: $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

Whereas Big-O is the weaker requirement of:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\lt\infty$$

In Taylor expansions, you'll see either of the two. For example, the remainder terms of sine after a $5$th order expansion are:

$$-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-\cdots$$

Which is *both $o(x^5)$ and $o(x^6)$*, as $x\to0$, because if we divide all terms by $x^5$ *or* $x^6$, we'll still have powers of $x$, which go to zero as $x\to0$. However, you might also see the remainder written as $O(x^7)$. The Big-O means the ratio is finite; if we divide that remainder by $x^7$, you'll notice that we will have:

$$-\frac{1}{7!}+\frac{x^2}{9!}-\cdots$$

Which goes to $-\frac{1}{7!}\lt\infty,\,x\to0$.

Usually, the little-o will correspond to the order of the expansion, and the Big-O to the order of the remainder, *but* that isn't what these symbols actually are defined to mean, so bear in mind the definitions. In this case, the $5$th and $6$th order expansions of sine are the same, which is maybe a more intuitive reason why the two little-o's were the same.

Comment: We always used big-O in calculus, never little-o. It seems more useful for limit computations e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: but little-o is more accurate in the context of Taylor expansion. The remainder is only guaranteed to be vanishing faster than all previous integer power terms. It's not guaranteed to be vanishing as fast as the next integer power. For instance, $f(x)=\vert x\vert^{\frac32}$ expanded to first order is $f(x)=0+0x+\vert x\vert^{\frac32}$. So the remainder is of order $\frac32$, which is $o(x)$, but not $O(x^2)$.